# Looping through records and processing them in batches

Tags: c#

I have a text file with X number of records that have 24 pipe delimited fields.

```
 ABCDEFG|123456|BILLING|1234567|12345678|12345678|...
```

My concern is with the `BILLING` column. I need to append this word with current date and a sequential number `BILLING-20131021-1` but here is the trick: The digit can or must increment only for each 10% of the record. So for example if I have 100 records, first ten of them will end with `1`, next ten will end with `2`, and so on. If there is an uneven number than the remainder will acquire the next sequence.

I started with two loops but that didn't produce the results. The the first loop iterates through the record count and the second iterates through the first 10% of records but then I can't figure out how to get the next batch of records.

```
for (uint recordCount = 0; recordCount < RecordsPerBatch; recordCount++)
{
    for (uint smallCount = 0; smallCount < (RecordsPerBatch / 10)); smallCount++)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply loop through, keep a counter and only increment the "small count" when you hit a defined condition.

ie.

```
int smallCount = 1;

for (int recordCount = 0; recordCount < totalRecords; ++recordCount)
{
  if (recordCount % (totalRecords / 10) == 0)
    ++smallCount;
}
```

Comment: This will only increment the counter once. I believe the condition should be if (recordCount%10 == 0)

Comment: Thanks shree, wrote this in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

Maintaining your current logic you could add another variable that keep the batch counter and simplify the condition on the inner loop calculating the batch size (10% of the total records).
Also it is necessary to check if the indexer in the inner loop doesn't exceed the total record count.

```
uint TotalRecordCounter = 101;
uint currentBatch = 1;
uint batchSize = TotalRecordCounter / 10;

// This will account for batch size that are not exactly divisible for 10.
// But if it is allowed to have more than 10 batches then remove it
// if((TotalRecordCounter % 10) != 0)
//    batchSize++;

for (uint recordCount = 0; recordCount < TotalRecordCounter; recordCount+=batchSize)
{

    for (uint smallCount = 0; 
         smallCount < batchSize && (recordCount+smallCount) < TotalRecordCounter; 
         smallCount++)
    {
         string billing = string.Format("BILLING-{0:yyyymmdd}-{1}", DateTime.Today, currentBatch);

    }
    currentBatch++;
}
```

Comment: the `10` needs to be a percaentage of the `RecordsPerBatch`. Also what do you do with `currentBatch`?

Comment: Answer updated, RecordsPerBatch should be replaced by the total record count. The outer loop cycles on every record, the inner loop use the currentBatch number to create the billing string.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying the issue is figuring out when you hit that 10% (and 20% and 30%, etc) of the file threshold.  Giving a good answer depends a lot on what your system is capable of, but there are many ways to do this with a single loop, and in the worst case, you can do it in a single, non-nested loop.

#### Can you find the exact number of lines in the file?

If your file isn't gigantic, and your file is line-delimited (one record per line), this is the easiest solution, just read in the file as a string array.  Then you just need to go through each line, and generate the last number each time, using `current_record / exact_count`.

#### Can you calculate the exact number of lines in the file?

If your records are fixed-length, you can take the file size, divide by the record size, and therefore calculate the exact number of records, and then generate the last number as above.

#### Is it sufficient to estimate the number of lines in the file?

Same idea as the previous suggestion, only use an estimate of your average record size.

#### What type of stream are you using to read the file?

If it's one where you can find the total length of the stream and your current position, you can calculate your percentage using that, instead of using row indices.

#### Final fallback suggestion

If none of the other suggestions work, you can always do a simple two pass solution.  In the first one, simply read through and count the number of records.  If you can fit it into memory, store each record and then parse it in-memory.  If you can't, just read the file to count the number of entries, then read it again.